# EXTJS : How to style a grid after refreshing it?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, styling

I'm using the following code to style a grid based on its content :

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
        switch(record.get('status')){
            case 'PENDING':
                return 'row-yellow';
            case 'REJECTED':
                return 'row-red';
        }
    }
},
```

However I can't call this method when I refresh the grid by doing this :

```
grid.reconfigure(cases_store);
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
var i = 0, record = '';
while(record = store.getAt(i)){
    grid.viewConfig.getRowClass(record,i,{},store);
    i++;
}
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "However I can't call this method when I refresh the grid" mean? The getRowClass gets called automatically every time a row is rendered by the grid.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli When I use the a new store and the "reconfigure" method, this function is not called. That said, I just found a solution. I'm posting it.

Comment: You didn't post any of that code, so your question doesn't provide enough information. Just looping over the store and pushing a class onto the node is masking the original problem, because as soon as the grid updates again it will be in the same state. The "solution" you posted isn't very robust.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli It works, because this code is executed just after the call to "reconfigure" is made.

Comment: Didn't say it's not working, just saying it's not robust and you absolutely shouldn't rely on it. The correct way to solve it is to have getRowClass be called, but you didn't post enough code.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I just updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I did. I'm sure there are better solutions, but this one works.

```
var store = grid.getStore();
var nodes = grid.getView().getNodes(), status='';

for(var i = 0; i<nodes.length;i++){       // Looping through the rows
    status = nodes[i].cells[5].children.item(0).innerHTML;  // Getting the content of the cell on which the styling should be based
    if(status == 'REJECTED'){
        nodes[i].classList.add('row-red');
    }
    if(status == 'PENDING'){
        nodes[i].classList.add('row-yellow');
    }
}
```

Hope this will help someone.